# Why does only part of git console output go into log file?

Tags: windows, git, batch-file

On Windows, I have a bat file that creates a git commit like so:

```
@echo off
echo.
echo -------------------------

cd C:\Repository\Other\notes-repo
git add --all
git commit -m "autoCommit"
git push
cd C:\Repository\Other
```

I call it from the command line like this:

`note_repo_sync.bat >> log.txt 2>&1`

When there are changes to the repo, then this gets added to the log file:

```
-------------------------

[main 013c443] autoCommit
 1 file changed, 1 deletion(-)
To https://github.com/raelb/notes-repo.git
   6bceead..013c443  main -> main
```

However, if I omit the `2>&1`, i.e. print the stderr to console, then much more is shown:

```
C:\Repository\Other>notes_repo_sync.bat >> log.txt
Enumerating objects: 5, done.
Counting objects: 100% (5/5), done.
Delta compression using up to 4 threads
Compressing objects: 100% (2/2), done.
Writing objects: 100% (3/3), 290 bytes | 290.00 KiB/s, done.
Total 3 (delta 0), reused 0 (delta 0)
To https://github.com/raelb/notes-repo.git
   28a2bf3..691fb4f  main -> main
```

Why are the extra lines (Enumerating objects etc..) not included in the log when I append `2>&1` to the command line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both `git fetch` and `git push` write their progress information (`--progress` output, suppressed with `--no-progress`) to standard error.  Progress output is suppressed by *default* when stderr is not connected to a terminal.<sup>1</sup>

There's no particularly good reason for this, other than "Git used to do this for historical reasons, so Git still does this for historical reasons".

---

<sup>1</sup>There are, or were, further bugs where explicit `--progress` didn't always work to restore the stderr output even when stderr is connected to something other than a terminal.

Comment: "Progress output is suppressed by default when stderr is not connected to a terminal". Is that a git thing or cmd line thing? It's unclear if the "no good reason for this" is the quoted text, or the fact that git outputs to stderr...

Comment: It's a Git thing: Git uses isatty() to decide whether to enable `--progress`. There's no argument for (or against) this use of isatty() anywhere that I can find.